# MVVM: как получить во ViewModel свойство модели при его обновлении?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamarin

Начну с архитектуры приложения.
Есть класс, описывающий объект:

```
public class Song
{
...
    bool isplaying = false;
    public bool IsPlaying
    {
       get => isplaying;
       set
       {
           isplaying = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
    }
...
}
```

Есть класс, отвечающий за логику:

```
public class Player
{
   public Song CurrentSong { get; private set; }
}
```

В App.xaml.cs данный класс объявлен как public static PlayerService.
Есть вьюмодель, которая должна получать свойство IsPlaying у CurrentSong у PlayerService. Сейчас во вьюмодели это выглядит так:

```
public class PlayerVM : BaseViewModel
{
...
    public bool IsPlaying { get => App.PlayerService.CurrentSong.IsPlaying; }
...
}
```

В XAML биндинг к свойству IsPlaying вьюмодели.
Но проблема в том, что свойство не обновляется при его изменении в логике класса Player.
Как мне связать данные вьюмодели и модели данных, чтобы при изменении в модели обновление поступало во вьюмодель, а затем и в UI?

Comment: Почему у вас песня отвечает за статус воспроизведения? Вам нужно несколько песен одновременно воспроизводить? А так можете подписаться на событие `App.PlayerService.CurrentSong.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { if (e.PropertyName == nameof(App.PlayerService.CurrentSong.IsPlaying)) OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsPlaying)); }` только не забудьте отписаться и переподписаться, когда `CurrentSong` меняется, для этого подпишитесь на изменение `App.PlayerService.CurrentSong`. Чувствуете, насколько глубоко вы спрятали смерть Кощея? Подумайте над архитектурой. Как тут говорят - у вас хвост виляет собакой.

Comment: У меня песня за это не отвечает, это свойство для отображения в коллекшнвью (скажем, человек открыл текущий плейлист, будет видно, какая песня играет в данный момент). Над архитектурой думаю много, переписывал несколько раз, совершенствуя. Получается, лучше не делать объект класса Player статическим?

Comment: По идее, тогда можно создать свойство в Player, которое бы получало текущее состояние песни, которая в данный момент проигрывается (или на паузе), и уже к нему обращаться из вьюмодели

Comment: Да, если вы не уверены, нужна ли вам статика, значит она вам не нужна. Если вас волнует грамотная организация компонент приложения, в смысле удобный способ собрать все в единую систему - копайте в сторону паттерна Inversion of Control и Dependency Injection. По поводу, что и где создать - пробуйте всякое до тех пор, пока не станет просто и понятно.

Comment: Да, очень волнует, на этом проекте я тренируюсь делать что-то более-менее серьезное. Спасибо за совет!